# Bind particular value from array object in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, arrays, object

```
testing:{"name":"Mohan,Rahul,Kanal,Rajesh,Gokul,Ramesh"}
```

Suppose i want first three name bind into label using angular ng-repeat.is it possible.Help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: use `limit` in `ng-repeat`

Comment: am used like below format. {{name | limitTo:3}} but it ll take only three string length.

Answer (score 0):

Please review below code it may helpful to resolve your issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="sizeCtrl">
            <ul>            
            <li ng-repeat="x in arr | limitTo:3">{{x}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script> 
        <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('sizeCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.arr = [];
            $scope.cars = {name: "Audi,BMW,Dodge,Fiat,Ford,Volvo"};
            $scope.arr = $scope.cars.name.split(",");
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.testing={"name":"Mohan,Rahul,Kanal,Rajesh,Gokul,Ramesh"}  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in testing.name.split(',') | limitTo:3 ">
  <p >{{value}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-repeat`:

```
  <label>
    <span ng-repeat="name in testing.name.split(',') | limitTo:3">
      {{name}}<span ng-show="$index<2">,</span>
    </span>
  </label>
```

Another solution: This shows first three names in array format:

```
{{testing.name.split(',') | limitTo:3}}
```

Another solution: You can split the string and then join first three into another scope variable and bind to it.

```
var arr = $scope.testing.name.split(',');
$scope.labelStr = "";
for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    $scope.labelStr += arr[i] + ',';
}
$scope.labelStr = $scope.labelStr.substr(0, $scope.labelStr.length-1);
```